# Component is not receiving a props from connect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have created a demo file where i have set up a dispatcher and same is been connecting through connect function to the App component.
But while I'm trying to access props in component, its showing me blank rather it should have a dispatch function.
Please assist to get through.

```
import App from "../Components/App";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { buyCartAction } from "../Services/Action";

const mapStateToProps =()=>{

}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    { buyThisProduct: data => dispatch(buyCartAction(data)) }
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)`

    import React from "react"

function App(props) {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="heading">Good Day Page</h1>
            <div className="cart_bar">
                <img className="img_scale" src="https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/08/1628224744_hp-envy-14-laptop-1600x900.jpg" alt="Lenovo Laptop" />
                <div className= "child_cart">
                    <p className="info_bar">Lenovo Probook 15 series </p>
                    <span className="info_bar_price">Price at just Rs: 37000/-</span>
                    <br />
                    <button className="btn_buy"}>Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default App;
```

Action creator as below:

```
import { buy } from "../Constants"


export const buyCartAction =(data) =>{
    return{
        type: buy,
        data: data
    }
}
```

Console output as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fGkL.png)

Comment: Here is a playground for the code below https://codesandbox.io/s/async-shape-pz1qx?file=/src/App.js and there is a function from mapDispatchToProps. Could you double-check? Console can be opened at the bottom right corner, below the result

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič, Thanks!! i started getting that function in my props.